# Merging multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql

Table: t1

```
Year    Project_Estimate    WorkStation_Code
null    159610              Totals
117825  null                Totals
null    1234                Data
3345    null                Data
```

Expected output

```
Year    Project_Estimate    WorkStation_Code
117825  159610              Totals
3345    1234                Data
```

Please help me with any inputs on this.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
select max(Year), max(Project_Estimate), WorkStation_Code
from t1
group by WorkStation_Code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select max(Year) as year, max(Project_Estimate) as Project_Estimate,
       WorkStation_Code
from table t
group by WorkStation_Code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use aggregation function assuming you have only two rows to merge:
The query will look like as follow:

```
 select max(Year) as year,max(Project_Estimate) as Project_Estimate,
       WorkStation_Code
 from myTable
 group by WorkStation_Code;
```